# What is $\tau$ in base $12$?

Tags: geometry, pi, decimal-expansion

I'm a big fan of both $\tau$ and the duodecimal system.

And while I can find information for $\pi$ on both, I can't seem to find the number of $\tau$ in base $12$. $\tau$ is given as $\tau = 2\pi$.

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 8):

$\mathrm{6.349416967b635108b2790423ba2a2aa38}...$

You can do `BaseForm[N[2 Pi, 100], 12]` in Mathematica.